# Snap used all drive space, errors when removing Snaps. System does not fully support snapd: error: no space left on device

Tags: 18.04, snap

In a nutshell Snap filled the drive and broke itself:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-logs

>> error: system does not fully support snapd: mkdir /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-390575120: 
>> no space left on device
```

I installed Snap/Snapd last year on servers which store and very occasionally serve video data, but otherwise don't see much action. They run ubuntu from 8GB USB sticks, and manage a few TB's of 500GB data disks. After an uptime of 255 days I ssh'd in on one server, and noticed 0% space on the / drive.

I was not able to free up enough space to make a difference with `apt-get clean` or delete logs from `/var/log`.  `du` showed snapd had taken up approx 4GB in snaps.  Worse, the system couldn't remove software e.g.

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop

>> Reading package lists... Error!
>> E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
>> E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
>> E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I had followed Unbuntu's standard snapd configuration, and now my server was not only not auto-updating, snapd was stopping me from fixing the problem.  Even snapd could not be removed:

```
sudo apt-get remove snapd

>> Reading package lists... Error!
>> E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
>> E: IO Error saving source cache
>> E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

>> Running error: system does not fully support snapd: mkdir /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-876453535: no space left on device
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue by clearing snapd's cache, then removing each of the snaps individually

```
sudo systemctl stop snapd

cd /var/lib/snapd/
sudo bash
cd /var/lib/snapd/cache
ls -lh
```

From that I could see 600MB in the cache folder so

```
rm *
```

Now I had some breathing room, so ran `snap list` and `df -h` to get the list of all snaps to remove.  Now I was able to remove all snaps with e.g.

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
```

`sudo apt-get remove snapd` was still not fully working, so I fixed a DNS issue by editing

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

adding in

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After updating DNS, I updated ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Then finally I was able to run

```
sudo apt-get remove snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap --purge
```

Hooray! System is now up to date, and has a healthy 1.7 GB of free space.  I'll stay away from snapd for my use case.